# HDF5 C++: How to get possible values of H5T_ENUM

Tags: c++, hdf5

I use the HDF5 c++ interface and I am able to write a simple testfile. h5dump of my test file looks like this:

```
GROUP "/" {
   GROUP "testGroup" {
      ATTRIBUTE "description" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): "this is a test"
         }
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "type" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_ENUM {
            H5T_STD_I32LE;
            "bool"             3;
            "container"        4;
            "dataset"          6;
            "double"           1;
            "int"              0;
            "string"           2;
            "vector"           5;
         }
```

When I read the file, how can I get the possible values and names stored in the H5T_ENUM type using the C++ API?

Additional question regarding understanding: Is the H5T_ENUM stored once per file and every attribute which uses it only has the int value or is the whole enum (all possible values) stored for every attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is the following:

```
  H5::H5File f( "/home/user/test.hdf5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY );
  H5::Group g = f.openGroup("/testGroup");
  H5::Attribute attribute = g.openAttribute("type");
  H5::EnumType type = attribute.getEnumType();
  int nMembers = type.getNmembers();
  for(int i=0;i<nMembers;i++) {
      int v;
      type.getMemberValue(i,&v);
      string name = type.nameOf(&v,100);
      cout << "HDF5 EnumType Members: " <<  name << " " << v << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to get the names and values of members of an enumeration is to use [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com). Using HDFql in C++, this could be done as follows:

```
HDFql::execute("SHOW MEMBER /home/user/test.hdf5 /testGroup/type");
while(HDFql::cursorNext() == HDFql::Success)
{
    cout << "name: " << HDFql::cursorGetChar();
    HDFql::cursorNext();
    cout << " value: " << *HDFql::cursorGetTinyInt() << endl;
}
```

Additional information and examples can be found in HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf).